# File sort order lost in IDE

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney

I'm constantly losing the sort order for the files in my Delphi projects:

[image]

How can I fix this? Is there a bug in my Delphi 10.4.2 IDE?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Self answering because I finally found it, and I want to spare others the frustration)

You need to follow a specific sequence because the IDE interface closes the *Sort By* popup menu after every action:

[image]

If you click on e.g. *Name*, the IDE sorts the files **once**. The submenu closes immediately (i.e. no visual feedback) and nothing is remembered.

The trick is to *first* click on *Auto Sort*, then reopen the submenu, then click on *Name*.

Now when you save the project, the settings are written to the .local file and applied in later sessions:

```
<ProjectSortOrder AutoSort="-1" SortType="1">
```

Comment: I've never seen a menu that remains open once I choose an item - it's been like this for decades (including ticking one). Is this how knowledge gets lost thru generations?